# Why do people say 'confidence trickster' rather than 'confident trickster'?

Tags: grammar, phrases

Using an adjective before a noun to modify it is quite legitimate, so it makes sense to say 'confident trickster'. What about the 'confidence trickster'? I can't see people's reason to use 'confidence' here.

Comment: They actually don't. People actually say: a con man, where con is a shortening of confidence: a swindler who **exploits the confidence of his victim**. from Vocabulary.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 'confidence trickster' is not a trickster who is confident, but a person who practises [confidence tricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_trick) - tricks that exploit other people's confidence in him or her.